# how to remain logged in on different hosts of the same domain

Tags: php, session

I have a shopping site, where each shop gets a host name: d01 ~ d30.
The system (=domain name example.com) should only need one login for each host. I keep track of the login with a session variable.

So far ok.

However, if a user jumps from shop d01 to d02, he needs to login again. I understand, that a different host starts a different session. How can I avoid that, since he is already logged in via d01? 
or: How can I transfer a session from one host to another?

I tried, but unsuccessfully:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.example.com');
session_start();
```

php.ini has the statement:

```
session.cookie_domain =
```

(blank)

Comment: Are the sites on the same server or different? Actually reading it again I think by host you mean server. Session data is stored on the server in temporary files by default. The most common way around this is to use MemCached as session handle then the two servers share the session data.

Comment: host like in http://host.example.com   - all on the same server.

Comment: @RonaldWiplinger I think your cookies (exect PHPSSID cookie) saves with that domain in which user logged in: f.e. d01.example.com, you need to set domain *example.com*. You can use function `session_set_cookie_params` to change it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan the function you've mentioned is for cookies but the OP is asking about sessions. While session ID is stored in cookies, they are different. The `ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.example.com')` should do exactly what he's wanting. There must be something else going on.